# ByteArray to Image display Flex - SQLite 

Tags: apache-flex, image, air, arrays

I have recently figured out how to use an SQLite db with Flex. Now I'm having trouble displaying the data properly. I've tried several binding strategies and I've largely come up short. I had undefined property errors, unusable errors, and finally! Code without errors! Also, code without a displayed image. Any help is appreciated as always. 
Here's my code so far; trying to keep it tidy, Async, and I've left an unused variable or two from my messing around with it. Thanks for any insight.

```
            <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
            <s:View xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009"
            xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark"

            title="NM1"
            >

          <fx:Declarations>
               <!-- Place non-visual elements (e.g., services, value objects) here -->
          </fx:Declarations>

<fx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
        import flash.data.SQLConnection;
        import flash.data.SQLResult;
        import flash.data.SQLStatement;
        import flash.filesystem.File;

        import mx.collections.ArrayCollection;

        private var conn:SQLConnection;
        private var createStmt:SQLStatement;
        private var selectStmt:SQLStatement;
        [bindable] private var dataField:ArrayCollection;
        [bindable] private var row:Object;
        [bindable] private var pngIndex:int; 
        [bindable] public  var pngTitle:String; 
        [bindable] private var pngByteArray:ByteArray; 

        private function init():void
        {
            conn = new SQLConnection();
            conn.addEventListener (SQLEvent.OPEN, openSuccess);
            conn.addEventListener (SQLErrorEvent.ERROR, openFailure);

            var dbFile:File = File.applicationDirectory.resolvePath("assets/NM.sqlite");
            conn.openAsync(dbFile);
        }

        private function openSuccess(event:SQLEvent):void
        {
            conn.removeEventListener(SQLEvent.OPEN, openSuccess);
            conn.removeEventListener(SQLErrorEvent.ERROR, openFailure);

            getData();
        }

        private function openFailure(event:SQLErrorEvent):void
        {
            conn.removeEventListener(SQLEvent.OPEN, openSuccess);
            conn.removeEventListener(SQLErrorEvent.ERROR, openFailure);

            // Make an alert Dialog
            // = "Error opening database";

            trace("event.error.message:", event.error.message);
            trace("event.error.details:", event.error.details);
        }

        private function getData():void
        {
            //status = "Loading data";

            selectStmt = new SQLStatement();
            selectStmt.sqlConnection = conn;
            var sql:String = "SELECT Picture FROM Data WHERE 'Index' = 0";
            selectStmt.text = sql;

            selectStmt.addEventListener(SQLEvent.RESULT, selectResult);
            selectStmt.addEventListener(SQLErrorEvent.ERROR, selectError);

            selectStmt.execute();
        }

        private function selectResult(event:SQLEvent):void
        {
            //status = "Data loaded";

            selectStmt.removeEventListener(SQLEvent.RESULT, selectResult);
            selectStmt.removeEventListener(SQLErrorEvent.ERROR, selectError);

            var result:SQLResult = selectStmt.getResult();
            // dataField = new ArrayCollection(selectStmt.getResult().data);


            if (result.data != null) {
                row = result.data[0];
                pngIndex = result.data[0].Index;
                pngTitle = result.data[0].Title;
                pngByteArray = result.data[0].Picture;

                Pic.source = pngByteArray;

            }

        }

        private function selectError(event:SQLErrorEvent):void
        {
            //status = "Error loading data";

            selectStmt.removeEventListener(SQLEvent.RESULT, selectResult);
            selectStmt.removeEventListener(SQLErrorEvent.ERROR, selectError);

            trace("SELECT error:", event.error);
            trace("event.error.message:", event.error.message);
            trace("event.error.details:", event.error.details);
        } 



    ]]>
</fx:Script>


<s:Image id="Pic" x="0" y="0" width="263" height="99"/>
<s:TextArea id="text1" x="0" y="313"
            />
```

**EDIT** I have updated the code now, with perfect, error-free code that does not display my image. Help!!

Comment: I had some similar issues previously. What format is your bytearray coming in? The Image.source property is looking for something very specific.

Comment: Thanks for the response. My image is saved as a PNG inside the db.
I think it was a problem reading the db, since I looked at the debug and had an error message, 2003 - a near error? NS? Anyway, it was about the "SELECT Index, title, Picture FROM Data" line, which I changed to SELECT * FROM Data, and now the error is "RangeError: Error #2006: The supplied index is out of bounds."

Comment: I've amended the SQLite statements so that there is no code error in Flash Builder, but I can't even populate a text control when I select only one field in the SELECT statement from db. Any ideas?

Comment: Well, the code right now is only SELECT-ing Picture, but then later you're trying to refer to result.data[0].Title and Index. In terms of the actual Picture display, if you scrooooll all the way to the bottom of this link there are a few options you could explore. I haven't loaded an image from a DB before, so I'm not entirely sure what to do. http://www.experts-exchange.com/Web_Development/Web_Languages-Standards/Flex/Q_23378802.html

Comment: Yeah, I've played around with the SELECT-ing different stuff to see what gets called and where errors are, just like I've been playing with a few different variables and controls - you can see I have a TextArea left over from trying to get strings from it. I'

Comment: I have tried SELECT-ing a number of different values from the db and tried binding them in different ways with different methods; I've still got a TextArea at the bottom that's not being used, and a commented out a method I was messing around with. 
Anyway, Thanks for the link! It's one I haven't found in my searches! I appreciate the input and when I figure this out I'll be sure to post easy-to-follow instructions for easy reference for all in the community! (including myself when I forget and need to know again...)

Comment: Solved - Initialize the original method helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you call the first function in the initialize() function as your program starts! 
I had forgotten it somewhere in my code testing. :/